# How to authenticate correctly in SharePoint Online from Azure Function with API Graph?

Tags: c#, azure, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, authorization

Ciao,

I'm working on a Azure Function that need to read/write to a SharePoint Online list using API Graph. I've some problems on authentication.

I've followed this steps:

1. Created one SharePoint Online site and one list
2. Registered my app in Azure Active Directory (single-tenant)
3. Generated one secret
4. Added Sites.Selected authorization to my app
5. Requested permissions to my administrator following this [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/controlling-app-access-on-specific-sharepoint-site-collections/)
6. Wrote code for use API Graph

Below app's authorizations:

[image: App's authorizations]

Below my code:

```
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "my-tenant-id";
var clientId = "my-client-id";
var clientSecret = "my-secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

var test = await graphServiceClient
    .Sites["my-site-id"]
    .Lists["my-list-id"]
    .Items.Request().GetAsync();
```

When I execute this code I obtain this error: **Message: Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token.**

How can I resolve this error?

Thank you a lot

Comment: Can you include the snip of the API Permissions you have granted to the Azure AD Application?

Comment: Ciao Imran, I've added the screenshot, I've added the Sites.Selected role as "application" permission.

Comment: Can you try changing the scope parameter to **`https://microsoft.sharepoint-df.com/.default`** and try Or if you want to give the scope as `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` only then try adding the API Permission like [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/QeNDwvh.png) and try.

Comment: Ciao Imran, I've tried to change the scope and I obtain the error: "Message: Access token validation failure. Invalid audience." but if I try to retrieve the access token with postman I obtain a valid token with roles. Now I try to request permessions Sites.Selected for API Graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

To resolve the error, I created an **Azure AD Application and granted API Permissions** like below:

[image]

Note that, you can only add **`Sites.Selected`** API permission based on your requirement.

I generated the token with scope as **`https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`** by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

 

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

Using the above generated access token, **I am able to authenticate to SharePoint successfully** like below:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/
```

[image]

Comment: Currently, all my trials hint that SharePoint REST API endpoint is not working with Sites.Selected and client secret. Would love to see an official Postman collection which proves otherwise...

Comment: Could you please show us how to get the token using C# code